# Is there a traditional virtualization other than docker that uses the underlying disk storage without pre-setting a limit?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, virtualhost, virtualization, paravirtualization

I know docker can fully use the underlying disk storage without pre-setting a limit. Is there a traditional virtualization technique I've missed such as Xen, KVM, virtualbox etc that can do the same?

Requirement:
1. open source
2. i can configure virtual IPs like kvm, xen etc.
3. can use underlying disk storage like docker (no need pre-set a limit so it can grow to fill all disk space for each and multiple instances)

Comment: In VirtualBox and KVM you can mount block devices directly to the virtual machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using VirtualBox you should be able to get everything required:

1. It's opensource
2. You can configure as Virtual-IPs as you want (see https://blogs.oracle.com/scoter/networking-in-virtualbox-v2 )
3. You can create vdisks (pre-allocated or dynamic), expand them and also use shared-folders (shared between host and guest)

Simon